# OpenLayers WMTS layer tiles not rendered in correct place when using wrapX

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I have a small openlayers webapp (for learning) that loads a WMTS capabilities file, creates a WMTS source from one of the advertised layers, and then adds the layer to the map. It works correctly without wrapX enabled on that source.

However, when wrapX is enabled for the WMTS source, the wrapped parts of the rendered layer are not rendered correctly. It looks like it is rendering the wrong tiles at certain locations.

[image: screenshot without wrapX enabled]

[image: screenshot with wrapX enabled]

The problem goes away at some zoom levels. For this example, when I zoom in, at some point wrapX starts working correctly.

What is causing this weird wrapX behavior, and how do I correct it?

Here is the code:

```js
const Map = ol.Map;
const View = ol.View;
const WMTSCapabilities = ol.format.WMTSCapabilities;
const TileLayer = ol.layer.Tile;
const OSM = ol.source.OSM;
const WMTS = ol.source.WMTS;
const { optionsFromCapabilities } = ol.source.WMTS;
const parser = new WMTSCapabilities();

(async function () {
  //////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  //  Create Map with OSM base layer
  //
  //////////////////////////////////////////////

  const map = new Map({
    target: "map",
    layers: [
      new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM(),
      }),
    ],
    view: new View({
      extent: [-100000000, -100000000, 100000000, 100000000],
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 0,
    }),
  });

  //////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  //  Add layer from GIBS WMTS service
  //
  //////////////////////////////////////////////

  // Load Capabilities
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://gibs.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml"
  );
  const text = await response.text();
  const capabilities = parser.read(text);

  // Create Source
  const options = optionsFromCapabilities(capabilities, {
    layer: "GHRSST_L4_AVHRR-OI_Sea_Surface_Temperature",
  });
  options.wrapX = true;
  const source = new WMTS(options);

  // Create and add Layer
  const layer = new TileLayer({ source, preload: 1 });
  map.addLayer(layer);
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>GIBS App</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/css/ol.css"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <style>
      #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>GIBS App</h1>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be related to the tile grid definition being bigger than the world when the source is in EPSG:4326 which is predefined as a global projection by OpenLayers.  To get around it I included proj4 which has a built in WGS84 definition which OpenLayers does consider to be global

```js
const Map = ol.Map;
const View = ol.View;
const WMTSCapabilities = ol.format.WMTSCapabilities;
const TileLayer = ol.layer.Tile;
const OSM = ol.source.OSM;
const WMTS = ol.source.WMTS;
const { optionsFromCapabilities } = ol.source.WMTS;
const parser = new WMTSCapabilities();

ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

(async function () {
  //////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  //  Create Map with OSM base layer
  //
  //////////////////////////////////////////////

  const map = new Map({
    target: "map",
    layers: [
      new TileLayer({
        source: new OSM(),
      }),
    ],
    view: new View({
      extent: [-100000000, -100000000, 100000000, 100000000],
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 0,
    }),
  });

  //////////////////////////////////////////////
  //
  //  Add layer from GIBS WMTS service
  //
  //////////////////////////////////////////////

  // Load Capabilities
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://gibs.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg4326/best/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml"
  );
  const text = await response.text();
  const capabilities = parser.read(text);

  // Create Source
  const options = optionsFromCapabilities(capabilities, {
    layer: "GHRSST_L4_AVHRR-OI_Sea_Surface_Temperature",
  });
  options.wrapX = true;
options.projection = 'WGS84';
  const source = new WMTS(options);

  // Create and add Layer
  const layer = new TileLayer({ source, preload: 1 });
  map.addLayer(layer);
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>GIBS App</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/css/ol.css"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <style>
      #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        border: 1px solid blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>GIBS App</h1>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.6.1/proj4.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixed my issue! However I'm still fuzzy on why this fixed it. Could you please give a little more information of why WGS84 worked differently from EPSG:4326? [The proj4js site](http://proj4js.org/) calls WGS84 an alias for EPSG:4326. I'm also not sure why the tilegrid definition being larger than the world would cause that rendered tile pattern. Thanks so much!

Comment: OpenLayers has its own definition of EPSG:4326 and only that is defined as global, so using the proj4 definition of WGS84 avoids using a global projection.  `ol.proj.get('EPSG:4326').setGlobal(false);` would have the same effect but might have side effects elsewhere in your code.